# xslt 3.0 conversion help - Sorting elements in ascending order

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have written xslt code to sort records in ascending order. However, the overall program terminates the job with a run time error as it processes large volume of records. One of the recommendation to improve performance is to write the code in xslt 3.0. I am not familiar with xslt 3.0, can someone please help me translate below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    
    
    <xsl:output indent="no" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:param name="implMode"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    
    
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
                
                <xsl:sort select="col5"
                    data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                
                
                
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            
            
        </xsl:copy>
        
        
        
    </xsl:template>
    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

I expect the person who made the recommendation had heard that XSLT 3.0 supports streamed execution, which dramatically reduces the memory requirement for processing large documents. However, not all transformations are streamable - a transformation can only be streamed if it is order-preserving, and since the primary purpose of your code is to sort the data, that isn't the case here.

In looking at how to solve this problem, we first need some numbers. Saying the data is "large" isn't good enough, it's like asking for help designing a bridge to cross a "wide" river. Give us the numbers.

If the data really is too big to fit in memory you may need to consider loading it into a database and sorting it there, or using a multi-pass sorting algorithm (no-one knows how to write these anymore, it used to be basic knowledge for every programmer, indeed every punched-card machine room operator, but it's rarely needed these days).

Comment: Thanks Michael for your input. The total size of 8 files is around 1 GB. This is a workday studio integration that retrieves 8 different files from workday cloud, stores the consolidated file into a variable, then
1) sort the combined file by employee id (1st xslt)
2) Group the above xml by a blocksize of 400,000 and split by grouping in order to generate multiple files with a row limit of 400k. (2nd xslt - uses 3.0 streaming)
I reduced the payload to 300 mb and the process runs fine without any time out issues

Comment: If you've got 8 files, how about sorting each one independently (in memory) and then using a streamed `xsl:merge` to merge the 8 sorted inputs into one sorted output?

Comment: Nice explanation about streaming facility of 3.0. plus one sir.